# Проверка <input> на заполненность

Tags: javascript

Нужно при заполненном поле скрывать сообщение о том, что его необходимо заполнить.
И наоборот, показывать сообщение, когда поле не заполнено.

Почему в коде выполняется первое условие, то есть скрывается блок, но при очистке поля второе условие не выполняется, и блок с сообщением не появляется снова?

```
var userName = document.querySelector(".review-name");
var nameTip = document.querySelector(".review-fields-name");

function hideNameTip() {
    if (userName) {
        nameTip.classList.add("invisible")
    } else {
        nameTip.classList.remove("invisible");
    }
};
userName.onchange = hideNameTip;
```

Comment: Коротко, ясно и просто. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в `userName`находится сам элемент, а не его значение.

В условии следует проверять так:

```
...
if (userName.value.trim().length) {
...
```

- `userName.value` - значение `<input>` поля
- `.trim()` - метод у строки, позволяющий обрезать лишние пробелы слева и справа (чтобы пустая строка тоже рассматривалась как ошибочная), возвращает тоже строку
- `.length` - поле, в котором указывается длина строки

Если явного сравнения нет (`>`, `<`, `===`), то `0` считается как `false`, а при длине строки больше (т.е. `1`, `2` ...) - как `true`.

Также можно и без `.length` - пустая строка тоже воспринимается как `false`.

Comment: спасибо большое! сработало, естественно. каждый раз спотыкаюсь обо что-то на вид простое и безобидное :/

Comment: Ничего, со временем приходит)

Comment: надеюсь ) нет опыта никакого программирования, кроме бейсика в школе, поэтому есть глобальный пробел в знаниях, который я даже не могу четко определить, чтобы понять, с какой стороны к нему подойти.

Comment: спасибо за дополнительные пояснения, кстати.